# Is it possible to disable MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN & UP

Tags: android

I have a problem with a second touch on screen and I would like to disable it. Primaly, object that has been touch if first finger is released is teleporing to second finger (MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN).
Is it possible to disable this event?

Answer (score 0):

Try add touch listener and catch and cancel ACTION_POINTER_DOWN/UP:

```
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

switch(event.getActionMasked()) {
  case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN:
    Log.d("ButtonCode", "ACTION_POINTER_DOWN");
    return true;
    break;
  case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP:
    Log.d("ButtonCode", "ACTION_POINTER_UP");
    return true;
    break;
  default:
    break;
  }
return false;}
```